# How do I chart a calculated percentage value in Crystal 9

Tags: crystal-reports, charts, formula

I am using Crystal 9 and have created a report showing calls logged by users, time taken to close the call, Solved with (allocated a value to the latter field depending on time taken eg. 1-59  mins = < 1 hr = 1), 60-239 mins = < 4 = 4.  I have then grouped the results by users and got totals for each of the Solved values

Solved1 = solved in less than 1 hour

eg group total shows (when record data hidden)

User1 (Total Calls= 74) (Solved1 = 42) (Percentage1 = 56.76)

User2 (Total Calls= 17) (Solved1 = 2)  (Percentage1 = 11.76)

Total Calls and Solved1 are obtained using Running Total Fields.
Percentages are Formula fields and calculated as follows:
    Percentage1 = Solved1/Total Calls * 100

My problem is that I need to graph the percentage values for each user for each Solved value eg.  56.76 and 11.76 on one chart. This would be easy except that Crystal doesn't let me select this field in the chart option because it's calculated from two Running Totals.

Since some formulas are accepted by the Chart expert and running totals are also accepted, is there a way I can calculate the percentage which it would find acceptable? Or can I put the total and Solved value in the chart and have the chart calculate the percentage somehow?  I was looking at using count and I can get the count to count all the records for a single person but not where say the value in a specific field = '1'
eg  count (call_id, )/count (call_id, closedby) * 100

Does anyone know how I can write that fomula or any other way of graphing a percentage?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Crystal formulas.

Set up a formula for Solved1 - something like

```
if {myTable.timeTaken} < 60 then 1 else 0
```

Next, set up a formula for Percentage1 - something like:

```
100*sum(@Solved1,{myTable.closedBy}) / count({myTable.call_id},{myTable.closedBy})
```

Drag and drop the formula for Percentage1 onto the report layout, then you should be able to add it from Report Fields onto your graph in the Data tab of the Chart Expert. (You may then want to remove the Percentage1 formula item from the report layout.)

Comment: I'd basically done Solved 1 but had multiple values....split into 3 separate fields and followed your suggestion and it worked perfectly! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue trying to graph On Time Delivery percentages.

I have three percentages to display: On Time, 1-3 days late, and over 3 days late.

I was in need of displaying zero percents as well, i.e. when there were no records that were "1-3 days late" I still needed to show 0% as one of my bars. The above did not address that. I ended using this resolution with a twist.

I created 4 formulas:

1. one to return 1 if the record was on time else 0
2. one for the 1-3 days,
3. one for the over 3 records.
4. one for each record returning a value of 1.

With that I was able to create my percentage fields using the `Sum` of one of the first 3 formulas divided by the sum of the "1" formula. Crystal would not work if I used the `Count(...)` function on a key field. It only worked when using the `Sum(...)` function in my percentage formulas.